# Can't have body height past 100%

Tags: html, css

So I have a parent div named .body and I have inside this body two container divs. The news container which holds basically holds the news all together in one nice neat little place, I have applied float: left; to this to basically keep it to the left, on the right I have a sidebar element with float: right; on it. Whenever I go past the min-height: 100%; I get a result like so... [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOpXA.png]

It runs completely outside the body container and out into the beyond... how do I fix this?

Comment: You add an element at the bottom of your body like so: `<p style="clear:both;"></p>`

Comment: can you post code which you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the floating.

You can do one of these:

- Add an element with `clear: both` after the sidebar.
- Add `overflow: hidden` (or anything but `visible`) to `.body`.

Comment: overflow: hidden; whereas applying does make the height 100%; it has left a ugly gap at the top?

Comment: @Twipply You should show your code in order to know what's happening, but I guess that the problem is that `overflow: hidden` prevents margin collapse.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a `clearfix`. you need to clear the floats.

```
<div class="body cf">
    <div class="container">
      text
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      text
    </div>
</div>

.container{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.cf:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```